# How to create an alias for an object's properties?

Tags: python, properties

I'm curious if anyone knows how to rename an object's properties?  For example, can I rename head.rx to be head.nod?

In maya, there is an aliasAttr command that does this.

Would love to do it in blender, too. :)

cheers!
-jason

Comment: Perhaps an image would help explain your situation better.  This might be python text.  I wonder if using the (¡M!) word is beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rename an object's properties, but you could extend it via its RNA, or add a custom ID.  IIRC, you can then add a driver to the original property, so `head.nod` ->> `head.rx`.  See here:

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Properties

That said, if animation channel usability is what you're after (judging by the names of your example) you might be better off just making a bone called 'nod' and then driving whichever axis is going to rotate that head downwards.

Not as extensible as Maya, for sure!

Comment: Thanks mike!  Not as extensible as I was hoping, but it'll work in this case. :)